# Boolean evaluation causes missing number error

Tags: expl3

I have been trying to implement Stein's algorithm for finding the gcd between two numbers and ran into an error I cannot figure out. Below is a MWE without the algorithm but illustrates the problem. For some reason unknown to me `\bool_until_do:nn { \binary_if_zero_p:N #1 }` results in the error `! Missing number, treated as zero.` twice per iteration of the loop and therefore ends up in an infinite loop. After some testing I have a feeling it has something to do with `\tl_if_in:NnTF` inside `\binary_if_zero:N`, because I can replace it any other conditional say `\int_compare:nNnTF {1} = {0} {...} {...}` (for simplicity's sake) and it runs fine.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l__binary_tmpa_tl

\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \binary_if_zero:N #1 { p }
{
    \tl_if_in:NnTF #1 { 1 }
    { \prg_return_false: }
    { \prg_return_true: }
}

\cs_new:Npn \binary_test:N #1
{
    \bool_until_do:nn { \binary_if_zero_p:N #1 }
    {
        % some code but for simplicity we write
        \binary_set:Nn \l__binary_tmpa_tl { 0 }
    }
}

\cs_new:Npn \binary_set:Nn #1 #2
{ \tl_set:Nx #1 { \int_to_bin:n {#2} } }

\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{ m }
{
    \binary_set:Nn \l__binary_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \binary_test:N \l__binary_tmpa_tl
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \test{6}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `\tl_if_in:NnTF` is not fully expandable, so you cannot define a predicate out of it.

No `...if_in...` function is fully expandable, actually. So you need some different method.

In addition, the guidelines recommend to use `protected` when the function to be defined relies on unexpandable functions; you can do

```
\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \binary_if_zero:N #1 { T,F,TF }
  {
    \tl_if_in:NnTF #1 { 1 }
    { \prg_return_false: }
    { \prg_return_true: }
  }
```

but a predicate form is not available.

In your case, `\prg_new_conditional:Nnn` allows defining a predicate, but it won't work. No way, sorry.

Comment: I did find it weird there was no predicate version of `\tl_if_in`. While we are at it, I think the `\prop_if_in` is expandable - might be a doc error. Anyway, I solved the problem based on your answer.